# Difference between てこそ and からこそ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, jlpt

> 「朝、起きる」という基本中の基本の生活習慣が身に＿＿次の行為へとつながっていくのだ。

I think that both「ついてこそ」and「ついたからこそ」can be fit into the above sentence. However, the textbook gives「ついてこそ」as the right answer and I don't know why.

Comment: The ついてこそ version means that  you haven't been learned of the habit yet, while the ついたからこそ version means that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ～た sounds like it's confined to one specific instance and not a general statement. If the rest of the sentence was also ～た it would be ok IMO, but again different from what the general statement is saying.

Think also about what ～て implies with respect to aspect: completeness of the action.

It is precisely by having got into the most routine of routines -- get up in the morning -- that one can move on to other activities.

Answer (score 2):

「朝、起きる」という生活習慣が身についてこそ、次の行為へとつながっていくのだ。
Only when you acquire/learn the habit of getting up early, the next step will follow.

「朝、起きる」という生活習慣が身についたからこそ、次の行為へとつながったのだ。(or つながっていったのだ。）。Only because he acquired/learned the habit of getting up early, his next step followed.